# Oracle - Get MAX value from concatenated fields

Tags: oracle, datetime, max, concatenation

I'm trying to retrieve the max datetime of a task started, grouping by task_code.
I've tried the following query to get all the max date, but the date and time are two different fields, if I try to concatened like,

```
MAX(DATEINI||' '||HOURINI)
```

to get the latest datetime by group, the query return empty. Is possible to do this, am I missing something?

```
SELECT DATEINI||' '||HOURINI AS STARTED, TASK, TASK_CODE
FROM TB_TASKS WHERE DATEINI IN 
  (SELECT MAX(DATEINI) FROM TB_TASKS GROUP BY TASK_CODE) 
ORDER BY DATEINI DESC, HOURINI DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try working with dates instead of strings like this:

```
SELECT DATEINI||' '||HOURINI AS STARTED, TASK, TASK_CODE
FROM TB_TASKS WHERE TO_DATE(DATEINI||' '||HOURINI,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS') IN 
  (SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(DATEINI||' '||HOURINI,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS')) FROM TB_TASKS GROUP BY TASK_CODE) 
ORDER BY DATEINI DESC, HOURINI DESC;
```

Check that to_date format depends of your context.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the format string and it worked for me. (at first, I thought that I didn't need the conversion to_date)